# How to handle comparative questions (this vs that cms)?

Tags: discussion

I know that generally comparison questions are seen as primarily opinion based and people are very quick to dismiss them.

However, as a long time pro, I can see circumstances where such comparisons are valid. For example when it comes to core functionality, scalability, security, extensibility, etc. etc.

Are we going to have clear guidelines on how much slack to allow on these types of questions without getting overzealous in just shooting them down and marking them as off-topic? Although it usually comes from the relative newcomers, I know that many pros switching solutions will have these questions as well.

They want the benefit of experience and not just what is listed in the "features", that's what we want this to be right? Professional quality solutions?

Comment: Example for such question: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/252/e-commerce-with-joomla is this question ok or not?

Comment: @HaraldLeithner, I think it was a reasonably acceptable question and shouldn't have been put on hold, frankly its not a comparison question as it is not really comparing a CMS solution against Joomla, just a specific type of usage vs Joomla and its plugins to extend or not. So its not a great example I am afraid.

Answer (score 4):

My personal feeling is we want to avoid "is WordPress better than Joomla". But for anything within the Joomla space, I think collecting user experiences is a valuable thing. I think the main thing is to encourage people to qualify their questions with he features or issues that are most important to them. So I don't think you want to avoid comparison questions that help people solve a Joomla problem, because it's difficult to get that information from other sources (both forum and JED have strict rules that actually hinder helping people sometimes). But we draw the line at helping people decide which platform (Drupal vs Joomla, Symfony vs Framework) to use.

Comment: I agree with Andrew.

Comment: Not really a comparison there. Something like features of Drupal v. Joomla I get but WP? Its a great blogging software that can be hacked into a simple website but hardly on the same level as a true CMS.

Comment: WP is a fully fledged CMS and has been for years. Blogs are still "content" but, like Joomla, there is a plugin for anything these days.

Comment: WP is a fully fledged CMS as MS Paint is a fully fledged image editor. If that's the standard you are using, then by all means. WP = MS Paint vs. Joomla = Photoshop

Comment: If you are comparing Joomla 1.0 with the WP of the day, I'd probably agree.

Answer (score 1):

SO has a nice page for this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

I think thats a good starting point, the are talking about that subjective questions are not allowed if they are not constructive.

In my option a "Whats better question" ends in the flame war and is not a good Q&A question.

Comment: Yes. Don't ask what's the difference between WP and Joomla. But if you've moved from WP to Joomla, do ask how to migrate or perform an equivalent function.

Comment: No, once size fits all standards have a way of totally failing the best interest of a new site. I have seen too many die just because they were regulated by incompatible standards.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question!

As Andrew says, qualified questions about a specific feature or issue probably make sense but generic Joomla vs. Wordpress questions do not.

I think it's important to have some written guidelines so that moderators handle these types of questions consistently.

Maybe the best way to write some guidelines is to provide some examples of what is acceptable and what's not and why.